# PHPMD and Coupling Between Object classes (CBO)

Tags: php, magento2, phpmd

I'm working on a Magento 2 CRUD functionality following the best practices (best described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115269/how-to-implement-service-contract-for-a-custom-module-in-magento-2)). On the project I'm working on we are using PHPMD (php mess detector). Among other rules, we have the CBO limit set to 13 (which I understand is the default). My repository is implementing the `get`, `save`, `getList`, `delete`, `deleteById` methods and the limit is already 12.

What would be best practice if I need to add other methods to this repository without overlapping the PHPMD CBO limit?

*P.S. I think this can be the case for implementations in other frameworks/platforms as well, not strictly related to Magento 2.*

Comment: Interface per method, implementation per interface. This is called SRP from the SOLID. This is a great rule. Prevents people from creating monstrous god classes.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this (maybe add an answer to the question if you need more room for the explanation). I would be really interested in an example if I'm not asking too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the greatest rules that helps to keep your classes focused and easier to maintain. How many times have you seen that:

```
class XXXRepository
{
    public function findOneByCode($code);
    public function findOneByParams($params);
    public function findAllByParams($params);
    public function findActive($params);
    public function findForProductList($params);
    ... 5000 lines of spaghetti
}
```

Instead go for this, embrace interfaces, make your application depend upon abstractions, not implementation details:

```
interface ProductByCode
{
    public function findByCode(string $code): ?Product;
}

interface ProductsByName
{
    public function findByName(string $name): array;
}
```

Using the Dependency Injection component you can alias an interface to its implementation. Go for implementation per each interface. You can make use of a abstract class which will help you communicate with the persistence layer via the framework of your choice.

```
final class ProductByCodeRepository extends BaseRepository implements ProductByCode
{
    public function findByCode(string $code): ?Product
    {
        return $this->findOneBy(['code' => $code]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea! However, isn't it there a risk to reach a point where you end up with too many files (which in a certain amount for big projects may become an issue) or too many dependencies to inject (in SonarQube for example you may have limits defined for the number of dependencies injected => in a CI/CD scenario your build won't pass)? I will research and try this and get back.

Comment: Define “too many files”. Another thing is if you have a class which has more than 3 to 5 dependencies it’s for sure violating the SRP principle as well. Check out its cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: too many files .. I don't know classes times number of methods .. 200? I don't know .. Anyway, it looks like I definitely need to invest some time in researching SRP. I will get back! Thanks!